# Access Numpy array from Python list

Tags: python, numpy

I created a numpy array from contents of a file
different areas of this array are assigned to new variables and stored in a list.
but when i print the list this is what i see

```
[array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype='<int32')]
```

this is what the code looks like

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[11, 22, 33],[44, 55, 66],[77, 88, 99]])
lists=[]
p=data[1:1,1:2]
lists.append(p)
print(lists)
print(p)
```

the p variable always comes up empty

Comment: Please create a small consistent example that runs, with example code, only a few number so users can just copy paste and run it.

Comment: @Joe i've edited the post

Comment: The Python convention for slices, ranges and probably other things is: the left boundary is included, the right boundary is not. So slicing from 1 to 1 leaves you with nothing.

Comment: @Paul Panzer oo i see, Thanks a lot

Comment: Just do as you think and then add one to all right boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1:1 slice contains nothing. The left limit is included, the right not. You should use 1:2.